# Overlapping Issue in Android TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, textview

This is one fragment which had Google Place API Integration.
Here is the first image:
[image: before selecting location]

After selecting a place that looks like this:

[image: after selecting location from google places api]

here is XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <in.vaksys.ezyride.utils.PercentLinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SearchGetFromLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_widthPercent="90%">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="FROM"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SearchFromMainName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hyderabad"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SearchFromSubName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Madhapur cyber tower, Hitechcitysad"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/SearchGetCurrentLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_near_me_white_24dp"
            app:layout_widthPercent="10%" />


    </in.vaksys.ezyride.utils.PercentLinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#CCC" />

    <in.vaksys.ezyride.utils.PercentLinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SearchGetToLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_widthPercent="90%">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TO"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SearchToMainName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Seconderabad"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SearchToSubName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Seconderabad railway stasion, Secondrabad"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Search_btn_swap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/swap"
            app:layout_widthPercent="10%" />
    </in.vaksys.ezyride.utils.PercentLinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#CCC" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_search_ride"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="@string/search_ride"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_offer_ride"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="@string/offer_ride"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is XML File , in here I didn't found any problem.

Java file :

```
private void ChooseFromLoc() {
    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
            .build();
    try {
        Intent intent =
                new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
//                                    .setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(), new LatLng()))
                            .build(getActivity());
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE_FROM);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(getActivity(), e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                    0 /* requestCode */).show();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " +
                    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);
            Log.e(TAG, " ajsd : " + message);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE_FROM) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(getActivity(), data);
            SearchFromMainName.setText(place.getName());
            SearchFromSubName.setText(place.getAddress());
            LatLng FromLatLng = place.getLatLng();

            FromLat = FromLatLng.latitude;
            FromLng = FromLatLng.longitude;


        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(getActivity(), data);
            Log.e(TAG, "hehh : " + status.getStatusMessage());

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // TODO: 23-06-2016 The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
}
```

Can any suggest why this overlapping is happening?

Comment: are you using ScrollView? Also add your activity class and layout file

Comment: Check both of your fragments main layout contains background or not.

Comment: I am not using Scrollview.
wait I'll upload My XML file @Polarbear0106

Comment: you must post your layout xml and we will suggest you any solution

Comment: @HarshDalwadi can you try to use normal linearlayout with weightsum attribute : https://codeshare.io/H5XNQ and let know result ?

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz I save code without Percentage Layout in your link , check it out , still the same problem happens .

Comment: @HarshDalwadi can you post your full activity code please for me with http://codeshare.io

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz https://codeshare.io/PtAK5 here is code .

Comment: @HarshDalwadi actually i tried your code and it didnt overlapped my view. But i used activity instead of fragment and here is the screenshot : http://prntscr.com/bpwwgx

Comment: It is looking, that you have fragment over fragment, and from this can coming these issues. To be sure - can you add for example green background for main RelativeLayout?

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz its must be fragment because app had navigation drawer .

Comment: @HarshDalwadi you cant use Drawer with an activity ?

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz no ...
not in my situation

Comment: @HarshDalwadi then you can connect  and startactivity for result in your activity and change fragments textviews through activity.

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz no. that'll not work in my application .
I have to keep that in the fragment .
btw thanks , I'll sort it out this problem .

Comment: @HarshDalwadi why not work, can you provide logcat ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said you are using navigation drawer then make sure that if you are adding an fragment then it should be replace by another fragment when you change options .
so please check it out that you are not adding multiple fragments in one frame .

Comment: Oh yes i tried that yesterday and I solve the problem .
thanks